# Extend Eclipse Search Menu Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna

I believe Eclipse made a change to accessing the search menu because I had added my own menu item using

menuBarPath="org.eclipse.search.menu/dialogGroup"

But I upgraded to Luna and this menu item no longer shows up, so the menuBarPath would be the most probable guess. So how can I modify it so that the menu item shows in Luna

Comment: `org.eclipse.search.menu/dialogGroup` is still present in Luna.

Comment: I see, where can I find the Eclipse Luna source code that lists the menu items in the menubar (Search, File, Plug-in, Text) so that I may debug my issue?

Comment: Looking at this again it looks like the menu bar path may have changed to `org.eclipse.search.menu/internalDialogGroup`. This is declared in the `org.eclipse.search` plugin